# Emacs -- Debugging an ispell error .

Tags: emacs, elisp

A few times each day, I receive an ispell error (like the following) that is corrected by restarting Emacs.  Any ideas on how to further troubleshoot this type of error would be greatly appreciated.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
  ispell-command-loop(("Brae" "Br ea" "Br-ea" "Bra" "Bread" "Break" "Bream"
    "Brew" "Bret" "Bred" "Area" "Urea") nil "Brea" 2229 2233)
  ispell-process-line("^Brea, CA ~ 92821\n" nil)
  ispell-region(1 6771)
  ispell-buffer()
  ispell()
  call-interactively(ispell nil nil)
  command-execute(ispell)
```

The document being spell-checked is in `tex-mode` (built-in -- i.e., *not* using AUCTeX).  The error (today) comes form a simple address at flush-left:

```
242 S. Orange Avenue\\
Brea, CA ~ 92821
```

Answer (score 2):

Try loading `ispell.el` and then:

1. Try to provoke the error. After loading the source file (not the byte-compiled file), you will perhaps get a more detailed backtrace, which will tell you better what causes the error. (You apparently already have `debug-on-error` non-`nil`.)
2. If that doesn't tell you enough, then do `M-x debug-on-entry ispell-command-loop`, and walk through the execution in the debugger. That should show you just what goes wrong -  where that function expects a number and has`nil` instead.

Based on your better understanding, you will likely know what to do, to either avoid or fix the problem.

If you cannot reproduce the error easily then #2 will probably not be of much help. In that case, you can try examining the code of `ispell-command-loop` to see if you can figure out where the problem is.

You can also copy that code and insert calls to `message` at various places, to try to determine where things go wrong when they do go wrong. IOW, provide yourself with some more info than that sparse backtrace.

Maybe someone else has a better idea - mine is pretty much brute force here.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I'll give all that a try in the next couple of days and report back -- :)